# Create a command to get the unicode hexadecimal number of its text / math input

Tags: macros, unicode

Is it possible to create a command that accepts either text or math argument, then prints or typeouts its unicode hexadecimal number?

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    Suppose the desired command is \verb|\getunicode|\\
    \verb|\getunicode{$\leq$}|      should print 2264\\
    \verb|\getunicode{ℝ}|           should print 211D\\
    \verb|\getunicode{≥}|           should print 2265\\
    \verb|\getunicode{α}|           should print 3B1\\
    \verb|\getunicode{\beta}|       should print 3B2
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are various issues here, see my answer but also how are we supposed to deal with one token versus multiple tokens, etc.?

Comment: @JosephWright For now, my need is to find out the unicode of a single input. I think you can add a restriction on the number of tokens so that it only processes one input at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but one could use something like

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \diaa_getunicode:n #1
  { \exp_args:Ne \__diaa_getunicode:n {#1} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \getunicode \diaa_getunicode:n
\cs_new:Npn \__diaa_getunicode:n #1
  { \tl_map_function:nN {#1} \__diaa_getunicode_auxi:n }
\cs_new:Npn \__diaa_getunicode_auxi:n #1
  {
    \bool_lazy_or:nnT
      { \token_if_letter_p:N #1 }
      { \token_if_other_p:N #1 }
      { \exp_args:Ne \__diaa_getunicode_auxii:n { \__text_token_to_explicit:N #1 } }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__diaa_getunicode_auxii:n #1 { \int_to_Hex:n { `#1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

with an up-to-date `expl3`. I've had to use a (currently) internal function from the `text` module: that could be 'written out' or a simplified version could be used.

One issue is that the hex value of `\beta` is *not* `3B2`: the latter is an 'text beta' whereas the one that `\beta` expands to in math mode is a mathematical italic beta, `1D6FD`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake with `beta`.

Comment: If I would like to find out the unicode of `{`, how can I use the proposed command? Also, the other special characters like `$`, ``\``, etc.

Comment: @Diaa `\__diaa_getunicode_auxii:n {\{}`  would work, although you should give it a proper public name if used like that not a `__` name.